# Excluding specific column

Tags: python, nan

I am looking at some trade data on which I want to run some Knn stuff... The Table hat the following columns: Quantity - Price - Years to Marutiry - Buy/sell - Segment - Broker

To run the analytics, I already encoded "Buy/sell" and "Segment". The Broker I want to use as a label, so I cannot encode him. The problem: in the Other Columns are sometime NaNs. So I need to remove these lines. but since "Broker" is always not a number, dropna does not work. Is there a way that I can say "Drop the row, if any columen buy Broker contains a NaN?"

... In Reality I got a lot of columns, so I would like a solution that allows me to "exclude the broker column" instead of needing to deinfe all columns on which this should work...

Maybe I could first split the dataframe in two pieces: BROKERLIST and REST. Then I could run dropna on REST and remerge it with the BROKERLIST. but for that i would need to remove the same rows of the BROKERLIST than I removed in REST. Any way I can easily do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `subset` parameter of the `dropna()` method

```py
import pandas

columns = set(df.columns)
columns_to_keep = columns.remove('Broker')

print(columns_to_keep)

df.dropna(subset=columns_to_keep, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this results in:NameError: name 'cols' is not defined